# Unable to install NodeJS 9 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (64bit)

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu

I have tried installing NodeJS by using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

The problem is, it installs an older version of NodeJS. So I found another way to install a newer version of NodeJS by the following command:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo -E bash -
```

But it keeps throwing me the following error message:

```
adam@adam-pc:~$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo -E bash -

## Installing the NodeSource Node.js v9.x repo...


## Populating apt-get cache...

+ apt-get update
Get:1 http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                     
Get:3 http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]                                             
Ign:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                            
Get:5 http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]                                           
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                    
Hit:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                              
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                         
Hit:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease                                  
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu xenial InRelease                 
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial Release
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Err:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en                              
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                       
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons                          
Fetched 451 kB in 6s (70,4 kB/s)                                                                                        
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Error executing command, exiting
```

I keep looking for a solution for hours now, tried around 10 ideas from StackOverflow and from different forums that I found on Google, but still nothing.

**EDIT:**

Meanwhile I found the solution.

I opened Ubuntu `Update manager` by the following command:

```
update-manager
```

Then I clicked on `Settings` and `Other software` tab and unticked all the `http://ppa.launchpad.net/` stuff I found ticked and strange (especially all the michael-gruz links).

Then used the commands above again:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Now I got `v9.5.0` installed.

Comment: There's a node module called `n` that allows you to install any version of nodejs. What I usually do in ubuntu is `apt install nodejs; apt install nodejs-legacy; npm install n; n latest`

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with that install command itself. If you were to look why it errors out, you can see that a launchpad package has gone 404. If you remove this repository, it won't interrupt apt and allow installing the package. You should be able to remove this removed PPA like so:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:michael-gruz/ppa
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Unfortunately it didn't work, but meanwhile I solved the problem, you can read it in the edit of my question.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use a version manager for node. The most popular ones are [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) and [n](https://github.com/tj/n).

Now you can:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs // install a really old node
npm install n -g // get n
n latest // get latest node, or a specific one with n v8.0.0
```